# opencart how to add manufacturers list like categories list

Tags: opencart, categories

I just start with Opencart. I need to have list of brands, like llist of catgories. I try so:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo "По брендам" ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <ul class="box-category">
      <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
      <li>
        <?php if ($manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] == $manufacturer_id) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($manufacturer['children']) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach ($manufacturer['children'] as $child) { ?>
          <li>
            <?php if ($child['manufacturer_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I add this code in default/template/module/category.tpl file.
I get this error: Notice: Undefined variable: manufacturers in....

How should I do this???
Thanks.

Comment: When starting with opencart, please read first the great post from **Jay Gilford**: [How to become a Guru in OpenCart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru). Then You should be able to move further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`category.tpl` is the template for the **category** controller. Its purpose is to show categories. Try to direct your browser to the `http://your.site/index.php?route=product/manufacturer` and you will get list of manufacturers. The template is `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/manufacturer_list.tpl`.

Your error is a result of one simple thing: the `$manufacturers` variable is not defined in ControllerModuleCategory controller (aka `category.php`). If you want use a variable in a template, you must define it in a relevant controller.

In order to obtain list of manufacturers exactly in the `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/category.tpl` (even if it isn't the purpose of this module), you need be done with few things:

1) In the `/catalog/model/catalog/manufacturer.php` file (model ModelCatalogManufacturer) add function (this function will help you to obtain the list of manufacturers from the database):

```
public function getManufacturerByCategory($category_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT m.* 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p 
        RIGHT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON 
            p.product_id = p2c.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON 
            p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
        WHERE 
            p2c.category_id = " . (int)$category_id . " AND 
            m.manufacturer_id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id");
    return $query->rows;
}
```

2) In the `/catalog/controller/module/category.php` file (aka ControllerModuleCategory controller), prior to `if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('confi...` insert the code:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $category_id = array_pop($parts);

    $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
    $this->data['manufacturers'] = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturerByCategory($category_id);
} else {
    $this->data['manufacturers'] = array();
}
```

*(Keep in mind `$this->data['manufacturers']` from the controller will be available in the template as `$manufacturers`. `$this->data['categories']` will be `$categories`, `$this->data['another_var']` will be `$another_var` and so on.)*

And since the moment you can use your `foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer)` in the category module template (the place where you did try the `foreach`, when you've received "Undefined variable" error) in order to output list of manufacturers which are applied to products from current category.

Best way is create another module, "manufacturer" module, instead of illegitimate using of category module. But I'm not sure that right now you are ready for this challenge.

BTW, I'm all for [shadyyx's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru) to the Jay Gilford's guide. It is awesome quick start guide for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

I have light solution:
Just add code in Controller:category.php:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
$this->data['mans'] = $this->data['manufacturers'] = 
$this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();
```

And View: category.tpl:

```
<?php
         foreach($mans as $mans_value)
         {
            var_dump($mans_value);
         }
?>
```